# Process a list of map to get a value of a key in the map

Tags: json, list, groovy, hashmap, jmeter

I have a list of map (parsed from json output of a rest request) like

```
[[Mobile:9876543210, Name:ABCD], [Mobile:8765432109, Name:EFGH], [Mobile:7654321098, Name:IJKL], [Mobile:6543210987, Name:MNOP]]
```

Original JSON was like

```
{
    "data": [{
            "Name": "ABCD",
            "Mobile": "9876543210"
        },
        {
            "Name": "EFGH",
            "Mobile": "8765432109"
        },
        {
            "Name": "IJKL",
            "Mobile": "7654321098"
        },
        {
            "Name": "MNOP",
            "Mobile": "6543210987"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the mobile value from the name

Tried some things but just not working out.

Trying this in JMETER JSR223 post processor using Groovy.

Comment: use `collectEntries` to build a map from it, where you have name as the key and the mobile as the value.  so you can use that map to lookup the mobile for a name.  if you only have to do this once you can also use `findResult`.  other than that, please add what you have tried so far and what problems you got with your apporach.

Comment: For future, please don't say "tried some things" - name and describe them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the `Mobile` based on `Name`.

Below code fetches the Mobile `8765432109` when Name is `EFGH` from the OP's data. Similarly you can change the value of **Name** to get the right **Mibile**.

```
//Pass jsonString value to below parseText method
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)
def result = json.data.find { it.Name == 'EFGH' }.Mobile
println result
```

You can quickly try online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5118325814198272)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example Groovy code to fetch `Name:Mobile` pairs from the original JSON response (use the code in the [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor))

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

json.data.each {entry ->
    entry.each {k, v -> log.info("${k}:${v}")}
}
```

Demo:

[image: Groovy JSON Example]

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks. That would be a good way to process JSON when I need to use each of the values (mobile and name) in the list. For now I just need one of them.