# get a map value by key from a list of maps in dart flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get the value of a data when the name matches the key in a list of maps.
Something like this:

```
List<Map> dataList = [];
await friends.doc("+2348******").collection("Friends").get().then((value) {
  for (var element in value.docs) {
    dataList.add(element.data());
  }
  print("${dataList.where((element) => element == "+23789900")}");
});
```

I expect this to print out: `John doe`
I found something similar but they didnt solve my problem

- [Process a list of map to get a value of a key in the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412123/process-a-list-of-map-to-get-a-value-of-a-key-in-the-map)
- [Dart/Flutter How to access element of Map inside a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61500529/dart-flutter-how-to-access-element-of-map-inside-a-list)
- [Dart: Return string value from list of maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64042522/dart-return-string-value-from-list-of-maps)
- [Get a single key value from a list of maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59220057/get-a-single-key-value-from-a-list-of-maps)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
List<Map> dataList = [];
await friends.doc("+2348******").collection("Friends").get().then((value) {
  for (var element in value.docs) {
    dataList.add(element.data());
  }
  dataList.forEach((element){
    if(element['name'] == "+2348******"){
      //print
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: This does not print out a single string rather, it just gives you the data as a list of maps which is what I have already done.

Comment: oh sorry, I just edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this code... Hopefully, it goes well... works with normal map at the moment.

```
List<Map> dataList = [];
    await friends.doc("+2348******").collection("Friends").get().then((value) {
      for (var element in value.docs) {
        dataList.add(element.data());
      }

    //Try this code
      var key = dataList.keys.firstWhere((k)
          => countries[k] == '+23789900', orElse: () => null);

    print(key); //output: 35

    });
```